# How to display unique numerical values from different columns into a single cell (separated by commas)

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, macros

I have a unique problem I have been trying to tackle with no avail.
I have scoured through the internet but only found partial solutions and not a complete solution.

I am looking for a function (or several functions) to solve this issue without adding references.

I have 2 Columns (Column A and Column B).

Each Cell in these Columns can be blank or contain 1 or more numerical values (numerical values are separated by a comma).
The User will be manually entering these numerical values.

Example:

[image: example1]

I need a function that displays all the unique numerical values into a single Cell and are separated by commas (in chronological order if possible).

Example:

[image: example2]

Now once this has been established, I then need a function to count the number of unique numerical values from this Cell into another Cell.

Example:

[image: http://imgur.com/Y46D6pR]

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the lister:

```
Public Function WhatsInThere(rng As Range) As String
   Dim r As Range, v As String, c As Collection, ary, a
   Set c = New Collection
   WhatsInThere = ""

   On Error Resume Next
      For Each r In rng
         v = r.Text
         If v <> "" Then
            If InStr(1, v, ",") = 0 Then
                c.Add v, CStr(v)
               If Err.Number = 0 Then WhatsInThere = WhatsInThere & "," & v
               Err.Number = 0
            Else
               ary = Split(v, ",")
               For Each a In ary
                     c.Add a, CStr(a)
                  If Err.Number = 0 Then WhatsInThere = WhatsInThere & "," & a
                  Err.Number = 0
               Next a
            End If
         End If
      Next r
   On Error GoTo 0
   WhatsInThere = Mid(WhatsInThere, 2)
End Function
```

[image]

To count the items, just count the commas and add one.